# Solr return 400(bad request) while indexing the json file from localhost

Tags: json, solr, localhost

I am new in `Solr` . I have setup solr in local pc. I am facing problem with the indexing of json file. I have one json file in local pc which i want to index in solr. it show some error which  i have mention below.

**Error**

```
D:\Solr\Example\exampledocs>java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update -Dtype=application/json  -jar post.jar timeline.json
SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/update using content-type application/json..
POSTing file timeline.json
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: {"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":0},"error":{"msg":"Unknown command: Name [8]","code":400}}
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
Time spent: 0:00:00.167
```

Please help me , how can i solve it? Thanks in advance.

**Log show**

```
ERROR - 2014-07-30 18:38:52.330; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:176)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1962)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:953)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1014)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:648)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2047)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1069)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:213)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:174)
    ... 32 more
```

**Json file**

```
{ "Name" : "Matches and Schedule", "timestamp" : { "$date" : 1400825267792 }, "_id" :   { "$oid" : "537ee50494" } }
{ "Name" : "meet Modi", "timestamp" : { "$date" : 1401449841192 }, "_id" : { "$oid" : "53886d3a2c" } }
```

Comment: The error you've included is from your json being parsed as XML, I don't think that's the same error as your code complains about in the first place.. And your JSON file is not valid JSON, if that's a verbatim copy (you're missing `[]` around the elements, and `,` between them).

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet.

Please post a snippet of your JSON file so we can comment.

Also, in these cases, Solr log files are your best friend, they will tell you exactly what it doesn't like about the data you are posting.

Also, you don't have to specify the host if you are sending to localhost, it is the default.

EDIT: Your JSON doesn't look correct. What do you expect it to do with stuff like:

```
"timestamp" : { "$date" : 1400825267792 }
```

First of, if you need timestamp is solr to be a date/time field it needs to be in UTC format. Second, Solr doesn't support nested elements.

Finally, if you are posting multiple documents via json, the format needs to look like this:

```
[ {"id":"doc1","field2":"val2"} , {"id":"doc2","field2":"val3"} ]
```

Note  that all documents are enclosed in square brackets and separated by a comma.